# Gitignore does not update a file already on my repo

Tags: git, github, push, gitignore, git-commit

I have a simple problem with my git :

I have this file **inc.conf.php** on my repository on github.
I don"t want to delete him from the repo, it's a basic config file.

Now, on my local repo, I have the same file **inc.cong.php** with my own config, and I don"t want this file will be commited.

So I create a .gitignore and I add **inc.config.php** in.
(the .gitignore is commit and push on the repo)

But when I update the file **inc.config.php** in local and tape `git status` :

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Swindle-Foundation5/inc.config.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But I don"t want to change the file on the repository from github.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.gitignore` tells which files you don't want in the repository. If you *do* put a file in the repository, then git is going to track it. It's quite contradictory to tell git I don't want to track this file (via `.gitignore`), but I also want to track this file (by adding it to the repository).

There are ways to make `git` not commit changes to that file on every commit, which is tedious and ugly. My suggestion is to work this out in your head first. Do you or do you not want to track the file? If you do, then all changes to the file will be tracked too.

One option you have is to generate the file via a bootstrap. For example:

```
# make a backup of the file
$ git mv Swindle-Foundation5/inc.config.php Swindle-Foundation5/inc.config.php-template
# add the file to .gitignore
$ echo "inc.config.php" >> .gitignore
# commit
$ git commit -a
```

So you basically keep track of a copy of the file, not the file itself. And add a script that generates that file (e.g. bootstrap.bash):

```
#! /bin/bash

cp Swindle-Foundation5/inc.config.php-template Swindle-Foundation5/inc.config.php
```

This way, you can update the template in the future, you can also keep it in the repository, but every time you change your actual configuration, they would not be tracked because they belong to a file that is being ignored and is not in the repository.

Comment: Yeah, good point, but like i say to Chris, if someone clone the repo, the file inc.config.php will be not ignore so he can push his own config.php ? that bad because there is private informations on the config.php

Comment: This is also a good option. In *this* case, the `inc.config.php` file *will be* ignored in clones of the repository, because it is now being ignored via `.gitignore`. You will have to use something like `git rm --cached inc.config.php` before it will take effect though.

Comment: @Chris, the `git mv` will take care of that ;) And yes Martialp, as Chris said, the clones of your repo won't have `inc.config.php` anymore, only `inc.config.php-template`, since `git mv` removes that file from the repository.

Comment: @Shahbaz, good point, I can't believe I've never thought of solving this problem that way (with `mv` instead of `rm --cached`)!

Answer (score 7):

`.gitignore` is only meant to prevent files from being *tracked*. Once a file is tracked, the ignore file has no effect on it.

You can make Git ignore changes to your file using `git update-index --assume-unchanged Swindle-Foundation5/inc.config.php`.

Comment: Ok, really interesting, so the ..gitignore is useless on my case. But if someone clone my repo, and change the inc.config.php, the file cannot be ignored so... so he can push his config file on the repo ? ... or the command git update ..... already ignored the file for all people who clone the repo ?

Comment: He will have the same options as you: commit updates to the file or use `update-index --assume-unchanged`. If you *want to* track updates to this file later, you can always undo this with `--no-assume-unchanged`.

Comment: Ok, so all user who clone the repo need to put this line : "git update ..." if they want push the repo... I think i failed at the beginning. Next time i need to think more before i creat my repo...

Comment: My answer works, but [Shahbaz' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21142493/354577) gets you closer to where you want to be, I think.